# How to use Excel/VBA to find column_b value with max column_c for each unique column_a element

Tags: excel, vba

The input data table will look like:

```
Column_a   Column_b   Column_c
Apple      Big        60%
Apple      Mid        30%
Apple      Small      10%
Pear       Big        20%
Pear       Small      80%
Pineapple  Huge       30%
Pineapple  Big        20%
Pineapple  Mid        20%
Pineapple  Small      20%
Pineapple  Tiny       10%
```

Expected return table:

```
Column_a  Column_b  Column_c
Apple     Big       60%
Pear      Small     80%
Pineapple Huge      30%
```

Comment: You could use Array/CSE formula: `=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$10=A1, $C$1:$C$10, 0))` to get the max column c for each distinct column A value, then just vlookup off of that.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to ask a good question.  Specifically, please post the code showing what you've tried, and what is wrong with the results you've gotten so far.

Answer (score 0):

Two very simple steps, both from the Data tab on the ribbon.

1. **Data > Sort** > on column C (*large to small*)
2. **Data > Remove duplicates** > on column A

---

```
Column_a    Column_b    Column_c
Pear         Small       80%
Apple        Big         60%
Pineapple    Huge        30%
```